# Generating CSV and blank line

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am generating and parsing CSV files and I'm noticing something odd.

When the CSV gets generated, there is always an empty line at the end, which is causing issues when subsequently parsing them.

My code to generate is as follows:

```
with open(file, 'wb') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
    a.writerow(["Id", "Builing", "Age", "Gender"])

    results = get_results()

    for val in results:
        if any(val):
            a.writerow(val)
```

It doesn't show up via the command line, but I do see it in my IDE/text editor

Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Could it be possible whitespace?

Comment: Are you sure last row of "get_results()" is not an empty line?

Comment: @grael I'm pretty sure yes. I've tried other examples (not using the `get_results()`) and i still have the same problem

Comment: I don't mind running this on my end if there is any way you can provide the csv file you are using.

Comment: @idjaw its the end file, not reading of a CSV

Comment: This is really odd as every example seems to do it. I see an extra line in every IDE/text editor I have, but when I `vim file.csv` I don't see the space

Comment: When I delete the extra row in my IDE and re-run my parser, it works fine :S

Comment: Every line of a text file should end in a newline sequence (CR/LF for Windows, LF for Linux). Editors will allow you to put the cursor on the following line, to allow you to start inserting there, but technically it isn't a line until you do. I'd fix your parser.

Comment: @MarkRansom This issue does seem to be newline. I'm using a Mac. Could that be the issue? It doesn't seem to be an issue with my parser. If I open the file in Excel and save as `ms-dos csv` then i no longer see the empty row at the end of the file

Comment: Mac OS X should be similar to Linux, it uses LF only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem the line terminator? It could be as simple as changing one line:

```
a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='', lineterminator='\n')
```

I suspect this is it since I know that csv.writer defaults to using carriage return + line feed ("\r\n") as the line terminator. The program you are using to read the file might be expecting just a line feed ("\n"). This is common in switching file back and forth between *nix and Windows.

If this doesn't work, then the program you are using to read the file seems to be expecting *no* line terminator for the last row, I'm not sure the csv module supports that. For that, you could write the csv to a StringIO, "strip()" it and then write that your file.

Also since you are not quoting anyting, is there a reason to use csv at all? Why not:

```
with open(file, 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write("\n".join( [ ",".join([ field for field in record ]) for record in get_results()]))
```

Comment: Just a nit, `'\n'` is line feed, `'\r'` is carriage return. Otherwise I think you're 100% correct.

Comment: Actually the part you changed was already correct, it's the `'\n'` by itself that I was talking about.

Comment: Sheesh. Re-fixed. (I hope LOL)